# Unable to push data into current object inside mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am using mongodb native and Node.js 6.5.0.

I have user object in mongodb which is structured as:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57d7d294d96a73d128c46db9"), 
    "id" : "105862592064", 
    "labels" : [

    ]
}
```

I have a loop (for each user found) get data from API and then push it into object attribute of array type. Where user id `user.id` and data to push is `resp.labels`.

This is my code:

```
db.collection('users').update(
          {"id":user.id},
          {"$push":{"users.labels":resp.labels}}
)
```

It doesn't return any error, neither it does update objects. What have I done wrong?

Comment: db.collection('users').update(
   { _id: user.id, labels: [] },
   { $set: { "labels.$" : resp.labels } }
) try with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$push` is for pushing a single element to an array. Use `$push` together with `$each` to push multiple elements. Also, quotes around the object labels should not be neccessary:

```
db.collection('users').update(
      { id:user.id },
      { $push: { labels: { $each: resp.labels } } }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this:

db.collection('users').update(
          {"id":user.id},,
           {
             $push: {
               labels: {
                  $each: //yourArray
               }
             }
           }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$set`

```
db.collection('users').update(
      {"id":user.id},
      {$set:{"users.labels":"hola"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include `{upsert:true}`:

```
db.collection('users').update(
          {"id":user.id},
          {"$push":{"users.labels":resp.labels}},
          {"upsert": true}
);
```

Upsert inserts new value if it doesn't already exists.

Comment: However, there is an issue. It creates new attribute called users and inside that users object it creates labels object which includes labels.